# How to add text beside hour and minute in CupertinoDatePicker

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino, cupertinopicker

I am using `CupertinoDatePicker` to allow user to select specific time in the current day, but i want to show text beside the selected hour and selected minute, is there any way to do this ?

**This is what i am expecting**

[image]

**This is what i got**

[image]

```
CupertinoDatePicker(
    mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.time,
    use24hFormat: true,
    onDateTimeChanged: (value){
      setState(() {
        print(value);
      });
    },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `CupertinoTimerPicker` widget.

It comes up with the default labels.

example:

> 12 hours 12 minute

Code for the same:

```dart
          CupertinoTimerPicker(
            onTimerDurationChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                print(value);
              });
            },
            mode: CupertinoTimerPickerMode.hm,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            initialTimerDuration: Duration(hours: 12, minutes: 12),
          ),
```

But, If you need the custom label as in `h`, `m`, and `s` in your case, you've to make a custom Cupertino time picker using existing code (from Flutter SDK).

Comment: yes the problem, just i need only letter beside the time, h and m, i will try and figure out how to change it from flutter sdk

Comment: This is what you need to look for `timerPickerHourLabel` in `date_picker.dart` file

Answer (score 0):

You can use CupertinoTimerPicker.

Referance: [CupertinoTimerPicker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTimerPicker-class.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).